# Authorisation issues

Tags: jhipster

I've been able to setup JHipster successfully using both Token and OAuth2 authentication. With both I can login using the default admin/admin account. However, in both cases, I get 401 errors when I want to access any API endpoint, i.e: http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/users

It renders a page with the following message:

Your request cannot be processed
Sorry, an error has occurred.

Status: Unauthorized (Unauthorized)
Message: Access Denied

Am I missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing any the spring security errors in the logs? Your angular session should be passing your recently acquired auth token for the admin user as part of the request to the api. If you want to access the api again outside of angular eg curl/Java client you'll need to request a new token for the user eg https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example

Comment: I cannot access it through Angular nor curl. I get a 401 error either way.